# how can use wire-tape in mule for statstict wsdl?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule

i define a web-service in mule i want to get statistics user that use from web-service 
how can use wire-tape in my project? what is wire-tape?   i have not wire- tap in mule pallet

```
<flow name="service-cxf-wsdlfirstFlow1" doc:name="service-cxf-wsdlfirstFlow1">
    <wire-tap>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="tapped.channel"/>
    <wildcard-filter pattern="the quick brown*"/>
</wire-tap>
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8882/OrderSvcs" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service  payload="envelope" doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" service="XXX_News" wsdlLocation="http://www.XXXXXtab.org/XXXX.asmx?WSDL"/>    
        </flow>
```

Comment: @DavidDossot mule is very new and there are not enough source and sample about this. toward other languages. documents are very limit!!! . fot all laguege program there are a lot of forums but but mule forum is  less than ten!!!!! really!!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidDossot mule is very new and there are not enough source and sample about this. toward other languages. documents are very limit!!! . fot all laguege program there are a lot of forums but but mule forum is less than ten!!!!! really!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood what I was saying: when you ask questions using StackOverflow.com, it is expected that you eventually accept one of the proposed solutions, or post your own or maybe even close the original question if it didn't go anywhere. Out of 13 questions you've asked, you've only accepted 3 answers, which means that someone helping you is unlikely to get any point since you don't seem to accept answers much.

Comment: @DavidDossot some of answers is not complete or related.  who resposne to me  change or amend his answer after i left my errors , there are not any source about source i forced to left all of question in to stackoweflow , if there were any source i search more and find (or resolve) my request, but now....

Answer (score 1):

The `wire-tap` routing message processor seems like a good candidate for what you want to achieve. From [its documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-WireTap):

> The WireTap message processor allows you to route certain messages to
>   a different message processor as well as to the next one in the chain.